# Confused about the cubic regression basis in the R package mgcv

Tags: splines, smoothing, mgcv

To understand the cubic regression basis constructed in the R package `mgcv`, I plotted out the 5 bases generated within [0,1]:

```
library(mgcv)
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.001)
y <- smoothCon(s(x, bs='cr', k=6), data = data.frame(x), absorb.cons = TRUE)
matplot(x, y[[1]]$X, type = "l", lwd=2, ylab='y')
```

[image]

According to Simon Wood's book (2017), each basis function should take the value 1 at the corresponding knot and 0 at all other knots. However, the plot above does not seem to be the case. What am I missing?

Also, this basis set is natural in the sense that they are linear outside the range [0,1], right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit in my original R code:

> y <- smoothCon(s(x, bs='cr', k=6), data = data.frame(x), absorb.cons =
> `TRUE`)

Below is extracted from the help of `smoothCon`:

> absorb.cons: Set to ‘TRUE’ in order to have identifiability
> constraints absorbed into the basis.

With

> y <- smoothCon(s(x, bs='cr', k=6), data = data.frame(x), absorb.cons =
> `FALSE`)

everything looks as expected.

Comment: +1 feel free to accept your own answer too if you solved your problem so that the question is marked as solved!